# Perl script to export sql query to csv

Tags: sql, perl, oracle, csv

The code below works, but all of the data displays in one row(but different columns) when opened in Excel. The query SHOULD display the data headings, row 1, and row 2.  Also, when I open the file, I get a warning that says "The file you are trying to open,'xxxx.csv', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted...etc. Do you want to open the file now?" Anyway to fix that? That may be the cause too.

tldr; export to csv with multiple rows - not just one. fix Excel error. Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use DBI;
use Text::CSV;


# local time variables
($sec,$min,$hr,$mday,$mon,$year) = localtime(time);
$mon++;
$year += 1900;

# set name of database to connect to
$database=MDLSDB1;

# connection to the database
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:$database", "", "")
or die "Can't make database connect: $DBI::errstr\n";

# some settings that you usually want for oracle 10 
$dbh->{LongReadLen} = 65535; 
$dbh->{PrintError} = 0;  

# sql statement to run
$sql="select * from eg.well where rownum < 3";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();


my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )             
or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag (); 

open my $fh, ">:raw", "results-$year-$mon-$mday-$hr.$min.$sec.csv"; 

$csv->print($fh, $sth->{NAME});

while(my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref){      

$csv->print($fh, $row);
}

close $fh or die "Failed to write CSV: $!";
```

Comment: Well, first off, you're trying to print an array reference to a file handle...that'll result in lines like `ARRAY(0x323523)`, etc.  Don't trust Excel.  Don't be afraid to actually look at the contents of a csv file (via `cat`, `vi`, etc).

Comment: Also, you have absolutely no error checking, so you have no way of telling whether you've successfully connected to the database, whether the table `eg.well` exists, whether the query was successfully completed, whether zero rows were returned, etc.

Comment: And furthermore, unless you're coding a throw-away one-liner, you should `use strict`.

Comment: Ok i'll be sure to do that. In my defense I started learning perl yesterday and have used google to help haha

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
while(my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref){   
  $csv->print($fh, $row);
  $csv->print($fh, "\n");
}
```

CSV rows are delimited by newlines. Just simply add a newline after each row.

Comment: I get next error: Expected fields to be an array ref at ... for `$csv->print($fh, "\n");`

Comment: @EugenKonkov: That line should have been `print $fh "\n";` because the $csv object is expecting an array that holds the row to be printed. I submitted an edit, but it needs to be reviewed.

Answer (score 2):

I think another solution is to use the instantiation of the `Text::CSV` object and pass along the desired line termination there...

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )             
  or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag();
```

becomes:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, eol => "\r\n" })
  or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag();
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. The query for exporting to CSV mysql includes defining how a line is terminated with \r\n. If you don't include "eol => "\r\n" after setting the binary flag, when you export, you'll find that the first row of data is merged into a single row with the header. You'll also need to remove the print $fh "\n" line as well, or you'll have a blank row between each row of data.